# How to put the author and year in italics

Tags: citing, italic

I use the `authoryear`style in `biblatex`, and when I do for instance `\parencite{jadadish2010}`, I get:

> (*Jadadish,* 2010)

But I need the author and year to be in italics, so that I get this:

> *(Jadadish, 2010)*

Is there a simple command to get this change ?

Comment: Hi, you've now asked three questions without getting any answers. Part of the problem is that you really need to add some code to show us what you are doing. This is called a Minimal Working Example. For how to construct one generally, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). For bibliography questions, this question is also useful: [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Since the default output will not put any of it in italics, it is impossible to guess what is going on.